# Java.lang.nullpointer when I call soapUi testcase by jenkins

Tags: jenkins, soapui

I'm having a issue with the integration of a SoapUi testcase and Jenkins.

I'm  calling the test directly by Ant and it's working. But When i'm calling my ant by jenkins , i'm getting a java.lang.nullpointerexception.

I've also try to directly call the ant by windows batch command instead of "invoke ant"

The jenkins console give me that

```
soapui-tests:
 [exec] SoapUI Pro 4.6.4 TestCase Runner
 [exec] 16:08:45,279 INFO  [SoapUI] Adding [C:\ESP_Testware\ESP_Tools\SoapUI-Pro-4.6.4\bin\ext\sqljdbc.jar] to extensions classpath
 [exec] 16:08:45,279 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [C:\soapui-settings.xml]
 [exec] 16:08:45,997 INFO  [SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory] Setting Script Library to [C:\ESP_Testware\ESP_Tools\Jenkins\jobs\ESP_QA_WS_REGRESSION\scripts]
 [exec] 16:08:45,997 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Adding listeners from [C:\ESP_Testware\ESP_Tools\SoapUI-Pro-4.6.4\bin\listeners\demo-listeners.xml]
 [exec] 16:08:48,025 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/C:/ESP_Testware/ESP_Projects/Test-Ws/Multi_1_1_7.xml]
 [exec] 16:08:48,586 INFO  [SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory] Setting Script Library to [C:\ESP_Testware\ESP_Tools\Jenkins\jobs\ESP_QA_WS_REGRESSION\scripts]
 [exec] 16:08:52,018 INFO  [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI tests in project [EnvDev 1_1_7]
 [exec] 16:08:52,018 INFO  [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Running TestSuite [MS_TEST], runType = SEQUENTIAL
 [exec] 16:08:52,034 INFO  [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI testcase [LogOn]
 [exec] 16:08:52,034 INFO  [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] running step [LogOn - Request 1]
 [exec] 16:08:52,143 ERROR [WsdlSubmit] Exception in request: java.lang.NullPointerException
 [exec] java.lang.NullPointerException
 [exec] 16:08:52,143 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [java.lang.NullPointerException], see error log for details
 [exec]     at com.btr.proxy.search.browser.ie.IEProxySearchStrategy.createPacSelector(IEProxySearchStrategy.java:70)
 [exec]     at com.btr.proxy.search.browser.ie.IEProxySearchStrategy.getProxySelector(IEProxySearchStrategy.java:44)
 [exec] 16:08:52,143 INFO  [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Assertion [SOAP Response] has status UNKNOWN   at com.btr.proxy.search.ProxySearch.getProxySelector(ProxySearch.java:193)
 [exec] 
 [exec] 16:08:52,143 INFO  [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Assertion [Check for existance of [a:Token]] has status UNKNOWN
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.CompositeHttpRoutePlanner.getProxySelector(CompositeHttpRoutePlanner.java:72)
 [exec] 16:08:52,143 ERROR [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] LogOn - Request 1 failed, exporting to [C:\ESP_Testware\ESP_Log\MS_TEST-LogOn-LogOn__Request_1-0-FAILED.txt]   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.CompositeHttpRoutePlanner.determineRoute(CompositeHttpRoutePlanner.java:59)
 [exec] 
 [exec]     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:709)
 [exec] 16:08:52,143 INFO  [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [LogOn], time taken: 96ms, status: FAILED at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:356)
 [exec] 
 [exec]     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
 [exec]     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
 [exec] 16:08:52,159 INFO  [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] TestSuite [MS_TEST] finished with status [FAILED] in 109ms at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:238)
 [exec] 
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:348)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:318)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:232)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.submitRequest(WsdlSubmit.java:76)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest.submit(WsdlRequest.java:238)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep.run(WsdlTestRequestStep.java:417)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:235)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:48)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:148)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:43)
 [exec]     at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:135)
 [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 [exec]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The SoapUi test case log give me that

```
Status: FAILED
Time Taken: 96
Size: 0
Timestamp: Fri Jan 17 16:08:52 EST 2014
TestStep: LogOn - Request 1

----------------- Messages ------------------------------
java.lang.NullPointerException

----------------- Properties ------------------------------
Encoding: UTF-8
Endpoint: http://dev.rxassyst.com/Blackboxqa/1_1_1/session/RxAssyst.svc

---------------- Request ---------------------------
<soapenv:Envelope     
xmlns:rxas="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RxAssystLib.Contracts.Data"  
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    
xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
   <tem:User>
      <rxas:Password>Blackbox</rxas:Password>
      <rxas:UserName>jm</rxas:UserName>
   </tem:User>
   <tem:UserInfo field:nil="true" xmlns:field="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
 instance"/>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>

  ---------------- Response --------------------------
 - missing response / garbage collected -
```

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? It seems a problem of Proxy IE Settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As venergiac pointed out it seems to be a problem reading proxy settings. By default SoapUI automatically tries to determine proxy settings.

If you are not using a proxy you can circumvent the problem by turning off the proxy. You can do that by supplying a soapui-settings.xml file with -t parameter to the testrunner. Easiest way to generate the file is to copy the settings file from your home folder on you local machine with SoapUI installed. Make sure to have proxy disabled in SoapUI before copying the settings file.

Comment: Thanks  I don't know why but it's seem that by running with jenkins the build is having issue to find the setting xml so in my testrunner call i've specified the path for the default soapui-settings.xml and now it's working.